# Are people standing behind the royal messenger deformed from consuming spice?

Tags: dune-2021

As we can see from this picture, everyone standing behind the royal messenger has their faces covered one way or another. The lady with hood is from the sisterhood; I am wondering if everyone else has their heads deformed from consuming too much spice so that they have to hide their faces in a totally tinted masks, especially five people to the right hand side of this picture.

[image]

Comment: Are they Identified? My thought is that they are members of the Spacing Guild (Navigators) who were *rumored* to have been changed by the spice.

Comment: From a wiki - "In the 2021 film, Guild representatives appear humanoid, but their physical features are obscured by ornate white robes and an opaque spherical helmet, with a semi-reflective orange face. These, however, are unlikely to be Navigators, as Thufir Hawat includes three Navigators in his calculations of cost of the trip, while there are more than three of these representatives present"

Comment: So likely just a stylistic choice by the director.

Comment: Rather than assume the helmets were tinted, I just figured those characters were breathing spice gas (why else would they need a fully enclosed suit in a breathable atmosphere?), but that's pure head-canon.

Comment: @Paulie_D, yes, they're identified, there're concept arts by Keith Christensen with "SpacingGuild_Helm-Robe" written on them. And it's not **rumored**, spice changes people, it starts with just blue eyes, and then progresses further (in the second book fully transformed navigators appear). But ofc, to interact with outside world they used humanoid semi-transormed ambassadors/representatives.

Comment: @Paulie_D, re Hawat’s calculation including 3 Navigators - either he guessed wrong, or the Navigators who navigate have to be paid, and the ones who represent the guild when witnessing the herald delivering the order and Leto accepting it are there as a courtesy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ones on the right (5 of them), are members of the Spacing Guild. They are affected by spice comsumption (abuse?).

> Navigators are humans who mutated through the consumption of and exposure to massive amounts of the spice melange. [Spacing Guild - wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacing_Guild)

The ones on the left *could* be these characters in the 1984 version (just my guess):

[image]

In the 1984 movie, *the Navigator's mutation affects his entire body, with 3rd stage navigators resembling either a giant whale or slug with a heavily deformed head. He also has a V-shaped mouth and vestigial limbs suspended in huge tanks of orange spice-gas*"<sup>1</sup>. it's what they look like:

[image: Spacing Guild navigators - Dune - 1984]

It seems to be a choice *by design* (director / producers) that their 'new' look is so different. Like many other props, each decade has its own design, each team its own view of how the book should be interpreted.

> Though Navigators are not present in Denis Villeneuve's 2021 film Dune, Guild representatives are depicted as humanoids in white, cloaked space suits with opaque helmet visors. Villeneuve explained:
>
> > We don't see the Navigators in this first part... I tried to keep all the space-travelling as mysterious as possible, like almost bringing some kind of mysticism or sacred relationship with that part of the movie. Everything involving space is just evocated and very mysterious. [Spacing Guild - wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacing_Guild#Depictions)

##### Footnotes

<sup>1. [article "Guild Navigator" on Dune fandom](https://dune.fandom.com/wiki/Guild_Navigator)</sup>